# How to use ffmpeg to download and edit video series with batch file

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, batch, batch-file

I have this example:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "https://goo.gl/JJbU5g" -vf "scale=1280:720" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -g 60 -b:v 2500k -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -preset ultrafast "output_video.mp4"
```

Can you move this command to a `*.bat` (batch) for me? I want to both download and edit multiple videos with ffmpeg.

```
for echo %%~f in ("kenh.txt") do ffmpeg -i echo "%%~f" -vf "scale=1280:720,hflip" -acodec copy -preset superfast "new folder\%%~f.mp4"
```

Here's the contents of **kenh.txt**:

```
http: //r3---sn-a8au-p5ie.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?itag=22&lmt=1477194355149141&mime=video/mp4&upn=mEwfl2i4vlY&expire=1477388332&sparams=dur,ei,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,ratebypass,source,upn,expire&initcwndbps=27500&ratebypass=yes&mt=1477366610&ipbits=0&ei=zNMOWMLIFsXBuAWY2bSQCA&ms=au&source=youtube&mv=m&dur=530.065&pl=26&ip=192.185.4.39&id=o-AOiKvtshjrEuBxS_tBhYshcvJ5GuyGtGu1ET5BZQg7je&signature=72B3D53EBECF0B1D7A33AF2F664D38F420CE3095.E203F4B341665A4CEF75304F72FD797B59872B4C&key=yt6&mm=31&mn=sn-a8au-p5ie&signature=&title=Final-Presidential-Debate-2016-Highlights--Trump-Defends-Aleppo-Comments-Clinton-on-No-Fly-Zone
http: //r5---sn-a8au-p5ie.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?sparams=dur,ei,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,ratebypass,source,upn,expire&expire=1477388332&upn=biNvyO0ZkGo&itag=22&lmt=1477156148919852&signature=E231B812416CAE3889D9566447BDEE0F2B25AE4F.6FA2987165D9A3B4C092F91570C9C9CA8BFB75CE&mt=1477366610&ratebypass=yes&pl=26&mime=video/mp4&ip=192.185.4.39&ms=au&dur=534.685&mv=m&source=youtube&key=yt6&id=o-AGrjm1damWDBNjwUlQ74uL3P8oVxKolD9a2M3Lu8cRQ8&mn=sn-a8au-p5ie&mm=31&ipbits=0&initcwndbps=27500&ei=zNMOWLLqL8G__QGQ162QCw&signature=&title=Watch-the-final-2016-presidential-debate-between-Hillary-Clinton-and-Donald-Trump---0
http: //r6---sn-a8au-p5ie.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ei=zdMOWOPHDZaRuAXe4ITYDg&ipbits=0&key=yt6&itag=22&mime=video/mp4&ip=192.185.4.39&initcwndbps=27500&sparams=dur,ei,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,ratebypass,source,upn,expire&id=o-AHvldCE3ot3jFplmK7BwafR9DNqEV5WUQ1JOwJkovduZ&signature=8F909AE04118A7D0A0B02157DADEDD666FE9DA5E.91459FE9950C8BF944C340EA4E17A57E8D334359&lmt=1476989685494727&expire=1477388333&ratebypass=yes&upn=o4nAnEeoh5A&mn=sn-a8au-p5ie&mm=31&source=youtube&ms=au&mv=m&mt=1477366610&dur=121.417&pl=26&signature=&title=Isabelle-Kaplan-Izzy-The-Baby-With-Amazing-Hair
```

Comment: file "kenh.txt":

Comment: Welcome! Press the [edit] link if you want to edit your post. You can press the `{}` button in the editor to format code. What is your exact question, though? Where is your problem, what did you try and what doesn't work?